# Unable to connect to SQL using pyodbc-Python

Tags: python

I try to connect to SQL using the pyodbc package, but get the error:
SystemError:
built-in function connect returned NULL without setting an error

What could be the reason for this?
When I run the code from another computer - I do manage to connect to SQL.

The connection string I use:
conn_str = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';'

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
I have ODBC and pyodbc installed on my computer.
Of course I set values for the database and server fields

Before I do connect I use a function that does logon with the username and password

Answer (score 0):

Because of your question do not have a reproductible exemple i can't be 100% of what I will say;

This is probably a driver [problem](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/341),  if you have acces to db2dsdriver.cfg file or db2cli.ini  you shoyld try to look in those files to find what is the exact name of the driver.

Following [this](https://simba.wpengine.com/blog/odbc-troubleshooting-tracing/) could help you to have more information on the problem.